# Flicker during scroll in single window?

Tags: scrolling, redraw

[image]

If I run vim without tmux in `urxvt v9.22` or `xterm 330`, it flicks after a full screen scroll.

```
$ seq 1000 >test
$ vim --clean test
```

execute `G` or  `/13$` and `nnnnnnn`, you should see it flickers. If you split your window with `<c-w>v`, the flicker vanishes away. If you maximize current window with `<c-w>|`, it still doesn't flicker. Looks like it only flicks when there is only 1 window.

`gnome-terminal` don't have this problem.

All test done in `256color` terminfo, `ubuntu18.04`,  `vim8.2 1-803`

How to deal with it?

**Update**

FWIW, scroll in terminal doesn't flicker, scroll in neovim doesn't flicker, only scroll in vim flicker.

I have tried apt version vim, and compiled vim7.4, 8.1, 8.2, and tried a version from some ppa, no luck.

I have tried to compile urxvt from [here](http://dist.schmorp.de/rxvt-unicode/), no luck.

This is my [rxvt](http://ix.io/2o0h), it's the only xresource.

This is my current [vim](http://ix.io/2o0m)

Have tried to turn off buggy options:

```
*.jumpScroll: false
*.borderLess: false
*.transparent: false
```

still no luck.

**Update**

Just learned to record terminal session by `script`,  the result for urxvt and tmux inside urxvt (top one is urxvt):

```
113^M^[[?25l^[[27m^[[23m^[[29m^[[m^[[H^[[2J^[[1;1H102
113^M^[[?25l^[[27m^[[24m^[[23m^[[0m^[[H^[[J^[[1;1H103
```

`113<cr>` search 113, it cause a fullscreen scroll , then vim hide cursor, turn off invers, italic, cross-out, reset sgr ( the ^[[m or ^[[0m ), place cursor at 1,1, clear screen, place cursor at 1,1 ,start display new content (102 or 103 in the trail) . The biggest difference is the clear_screen (t_cl in termcap) escape sequence, urxvt use `^[[H^[[2J`, tmux use `^[[H^[[J`, I tried to use tmux `t_cl` in urxvt , but still no luck.

I don't use xterm, you can post answer that only work for urxvt, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't really this problem on my machine. Only tested xterm with the default settings. Perhaps there is some xterm setting that would affect this (I believe urxvt uses much of the same settings)?

Comment: @MartinTournoij This is my [rxvt](http://ix.io/2o0h), it's the only xresource, I have stopped loading `~/.Xresources.d/xterm`, still no luck.

Comment: Maybe `:h 'ttyscroll'` can help?

Comment: @Matt Tried  `ttyscroll=1` and `ttyscroll=999`, not working.